# Workflow management software for Linux

Tags: software-rec, productivity

I'm not really sure if the software that I need is a workflow management software.

Basically I need something that I can host on a Linux server that will provide the following functionality:

- support a pre-set workflow, allowing users to see where they are currently in the workflow, and whether they are expected to act, or they should wait for some external action
- users also need to see the deadline of the entire workflow and the steps that are still ahead
- not absolutely required, but it would be nice to have the ability to track versions of files inside the workflow
- ability to add support materials for steps in the workflow (let's say the workflow went back to the user, to fix some errors, so he will have links to wiki and other relevant materials for that step)
- notifications, for example for the users, when the workflow gets back into a state where they are expected to act

Comment: Is [issue-tracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Issue_tracking) a fair approximation, maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/).

> Some of the main features of Redmine are:
>
> ```
> Multiple projects support
> Flexible role based access control
> Flexible issue tracking system
> Gantt chart and calendar
> News, documents & files management
> Feeds & email notifications
> Per project wiki
> Per project forums
> Time tracking
> Custom fields for issues, time-entries, projects and users
> SCM integration (SVN, CVS, Git, Mercurial, Bazaar and Darcs)
> Issue creation via email
> Multiple LDAP authentication support
> User self-registration support
> Multilanguage support
> Multiple databases support
> ```

(from Redmine homepage)

There is also a lot of plugins to extend it, and if there isn't a plugin that you need you can create your own easily. ;)

Answer (score 0):

"Trac" might be an option for you.
http://trac.edgewall.org/